# How to insert chinese characters in sql server database using insert query in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

**Chinese characters are inserting as '??' in table.**

I have tried like this but its not working.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Sp_InsertPersonalInformation]
(
@NameIn_Chinese  NVARCHAR(100)=NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_PersonalInformation(ChineseName) VALUES (N''+@NameIn_Chinese+'')
END
```

The below query is working. but through stored procedure i'm not able to insert in a correct format.

```
INSERT INTO TBL_PERSONALINFORMATION(ChineseName) VALUES (N'你好')
```

Comment: Which DB are you using? Is your server configured to support UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: How are you executing the stored procedure, though? The `N''+@var+''` does nothing since the parameter is already an `NVARCHAR` -- but it must be passed as a Unicode string on the client side too.

Comment: Thank u David... I did a small mistake i've given SqlDbType.VarChar instead of SqlDbType.NVarChar in my DAL file. Thank u so much..