# Simplified and Traditional Chinese characters are stored as ? in the Sybase database using Liquibase in Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, sybase, liquibase

I am trying to save Chinese characters in Sybase database with Liquibase, but ended up getting "?" for each of the characters.
I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032799/how-to-insert-chinese-characters-in-sql-server-database-using-insert-query-in-st)

but it didn't help.

I am using the 3.6.1 version of liquibase-core (also tried with 3.6.3)

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Here are the contents of CREATE and INSERT scripts
CREATE Table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <databaseChangeLog
            xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
            xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
                            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd" >

        <changeSet author="me" id="1" >
            <createTable tableName="person" >
                <column name="name" type="unitext" encoding="utf8" >
                </column>
                <column name="address" type="VARCHAR(255)" />
            </createTable>
            <rollback>
                <dropTable tableName="person"/>
            </rollback>
        </changeSet>
    </databaseChangeLog>
```

INSERT Query:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

<changeSet author="me" id="2" runOnChange="true" >
    <insert tableName="person" >
        <column name="name" value="汉字" encoding="utf8"/>
        <column name="address" value="DNI"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

And when I start the Spring Boot application, the scripts get executed. And I get "??" in place of "汉字" when I query the table.

As in the code, I have already put encoding=utf8. Not sure what is missing.

Sybase version: ASE 15.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the solution lies in the DB connection params.

jdbc:sybase:host:port?**useUnicode=true&CHARSET=utf8**

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you did not specify *which* Sybase database type you are working with (there are 3 different Sybase database products), what you are showing is the client side of things. What is equally important is whether the server is set up to support Unicode characters (various ways of doing that). That is what you need to find out.

Comment: I have updated the Sybase version in the question. And there are few other tables in the DB which already contains the Chinese characters (these were inserted through YART and not through Liquibase). For the very first time I am trying through Liquibase for the Chinese characters.
I too suspected that this has to do with the DB server setup. But as other tables already contain Chinese characters, I doubted on the Liquibase configuration.